# Calculus proof of ln(ab)= lna + lnb

Tags: calculus, logarithms, proof-explanation

My calculus book states the following theorem of the properties of natural logarithms:

If a, b > 0 , then
ln(ab)= lna + lnb

The author goes on to prove this theorem as follows

[image: Click here for proof]

I do not understand what property allowed the author to use the substitution U = t/a because the original variable in the second integral is "t" and clearly U is not the same as t. Shouldn't U = t.

Comment: It is a trivial substitution to say $\int_a^b f(u) \ du = \int_a^b f(t) \ dt.$  Equivalently, I could say $\int_1^b \frac 1y\ dy = \ln b$ doesn't care what is the variable of integration.

Comment: Before you can understand this proof you need to understand the general idea behind "substitution" in a definite integral. You will find that somewhere earlier in your calculus book.

Comment: Note that there is a typo in the last line of the screenshot from the calculus book.  $\int_1^{ab} \frac{a}{t} \cdot \frac{1}{a}\,dt$ should be $\int_a^{ab} \frac{a}{t} \cdot \frac{1}{a} \, dt$.

Comment: I see you all use u=t/a to replace the variable, but how do we change the interval is not being proved. Do you have to use the mechanism 'change of variables' to explain why the interval changes for integral from [ab,b] to [b,1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a definite integral, the variable which you are integrating with respect to is a "dummy variable": in the sense that it does not matter what you call it. Thus,
$$\int_a^b\frac1tdt,\;\int_a^b\frac1udu,\;\int_a^b\frac1sds,\;\int_a^b\frac1\zeta d\zeta$$
all mean exactly the same thing and have exactly the same value. After the substitution $u=t/a$, we obtain $$\int_a^{ab}\frac1tdt=\int_1^b\frac1udu=\ln b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach.

Since $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac1t$, we have $\ln'(x)=\frac1x$.

Let
$
f(x)=\ln(ax)- \ln(a) - \ln(x)
$.
Then $f'(x)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ imply $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.